# SQL: Where MYID = ANY?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In a SQL query, that contains

```
... WHERE MYID = @1 ....
```

I have to manage 2 cases
1) There is a filter on a column, @1 will be a number (1,2,X...)

2) There is no filter on that column, @1 will be ...? (*ANY*)

Is there something for this "any" (SQL Server 2005) ?

**PS.**
Obviously, I understand that I can remove the "where".

**PPS.**
I explain myself for better understanding: I have this query in the code, and would like to pass an integer as parameter when the filter is ON, and "something" when my filter is OFF.

```
if (filterOn)
    GetFoos(fooID);
else
    GetFoos("ANY");

GetFoos(param1): "select * from FOOS where FOOID = {0}", param1
```

Comment: Why don't you just perform 2 separating query instead. Choose one based on @1 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having

```
"select * from FOO where FOOID = {0}", param
```

use param="FOOID" when there is no param to filter, this will give

```
select * from FOO where FOOID = FOOID // removing the filter
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a `UNION ALL` of the two statements:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   myid = @col
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   @col IS NULL
```

or just split them in an `IF / ELSE` block of a stored procedures.

Either way, the optimizer will be able to optimize the queries separately, completely ignoring one of them depending on the value of `@col`.

Comment: @serhio: just pass a `NULL` instead of `'ANY'`.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something along this line:

```
 where (myid = @id or @id is null)
```

so you will only filter when `@id` contains a value and not when it is `null`.

Comment: The performance of that penalises the case when there **is** a specific `@id` to look up as discussed here http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html

Comment: @serhio: the ID column shouldn't be null, but the parameter could be, to signal you really don't want to filter on it. Or you could use the value 0 to mean "don't filter".

Comment: Ok, I got the point. Now figure that this is not a procedure, but a SQL string is like `select * from FOOS where FOOID = {0}`...

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the where or and clause if there is no filter on that column.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to filter on a particular column, just don't filter on that column. Remove the `WHERE MYID =` entirely

Comment: I have a string query. Is there a possibility to keep it like is, but just replacing something instead of "any"?

Comment: If you use `LIKE` instead of `=` then I think you can use `WHERE MYID LIKE %` to match anything. EDIT: And `WHERE MYID LIKE 42` will still match 42 only.

Comment: @serhio: where are you performing this query? Some programming language or stored procedure?

Comment: Why can't you change the query?

Comment: @serhio: `LIKE 4` doesn't match `42`

Comment: I added a explanation in the topic. Will `LIKE` be the same that `=` in my case?

Comment: Yes, but you have to use `"%"` instead of `"ANY"`. EDIT: And, of course, `=` won't match anything when you give `%`.