# CASE syntax inside a WHERE clause on MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL syntax on MSSQL

```
SELECT
  id,
  firstName,
  lastName
FROM
  Person
WHERE
  ((CASE WHEN @Filter = 'firstName' THEN @Value END) = firstName ) or
  ((CASE WHEN @Filter = 'lastName' THEN @Value END) = lastName )
```

It's working but I don't know if there is a better and more efficient way to do this.

Thanks in advanceName

Comment: That should compile, but I don't think it does what you want it too... Is there a @Name parameter that is being passed in addition to @Filter?

Comment: Sorry, I just fix the SQL Syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may compile, but it seems like something's missing.  `@Filter` apparently represents the *field* you're filtering on, and one would expect to see a *value* to check against the field, like so

```
SELECT
  id,
  firstName,
  lastName
FROM
  Person
WHERE @Value =
   CASE WHEN @Filter = 'firstName' THEN firstName
        WHEN @Filter = 'lastName' THEN lastName
    END
```

If this is your intent, then only one `CASE` expression is needed, regardless of the number of possible filter fields.

Either way, the `CASE` statement is going to be very efficient.  SQL Server will see that the `WHEN` expressions are comparing scalar values and optimize accordingly (in other words, the value of `@Filter` does not need to be re-evaluated for every row).

Comment: This will **not** be efficient unless `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is used and the OP is on at least `SQL 2008 SP1 CU5 (10.0.2746)` or `SQL 2008 R2 CU1 (10.50.1702)` (Version numbers from here http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html BTW)

Comment: @Martin, thanks for the note.  Is there a better way to write this for earlier versions?

Comment: splitting them out in 2 cases with a `UNION ALL` should work better for those (An idea I got from this answer yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754619/sql-where-myid-any/5754664#5754664)

Answer (score 9):

In this example you don't really need `CASE` at all.  `AND` and `OR` will run faster:

```
SELECT
  id,
  firstName,
  lastName
FROM
  Person
WHERE
  (@Filter = 'firstName' AND @Value = firstName) OR
  (@Filter = 'lastName' AND @Value = lastName)
```